# JPA and Hibernate problem, identifier of an instance of x

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA/Hibernate entity which uses a composite key as the primary key. When I read the object from the database and make an update I get the error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of navigation.external.CustomerNavigationType was altered from navigation.external.CustomerNavigationTypeId@7ccdbbc5 to navigation.external.CustomerNavigationTypeId@bba8c505
```

The error happens when I flush.

I have read several other stackoverflow posts and tried to implement the suggestions, but I still get the error. Can you see what I am missing?

Entity:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "CustomerNavigationType")
@IdClass(CustomerNavigationTypeId.class)
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class CustomerNavigationType {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "BANKNR")
    private BigDecimal bankNr;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAVTYPE")
    private String navType;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "JUREN")
    private String juren;

    @Column(name = "STATU")
    private String state;
}
```

CompositeKey:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class CustomerNavigationTypeId implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal bankNr;

    private String navType;

    private String juren;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        CustomerNavigationTypeId other = (CustomerNavigationTypeId) obj;
        return Objects.equals(bankNr, other.getBankNr())
            && Objects.equals(navType, other.getNavType())
            && Objects.equals(juren, other.juren());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bankNr, navType, juren);
    }
}
```

DatabaseClient code:

```java
EntityManager em = entityManagerProducer.getEntityManager();
CustomerNavigationTypeId compositeId = new CustomerNavigationTypeId(
   BigDecimal.valueOf(1),
   "NAVRULE1",
   "2021-08-05 22:15:00.384395");

em.getTransaction().begin();
CustomerNavigationType customerNavigationType = em.find(CustomerNavigationType.class, compositeId);
customerNavigationType.setState("ACTIVE");
em.flush();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: I don't exactly what happens. But why do you use BigDecimal for the bankNr?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using @EmbeddedId and @Embeddable instaead of @Idclass etc.